# Citrix: Using Browser Content Redirection , Pop ups opening in new tab

Tags: popup, popupwindow, citrix

I am using Browser Content Redirection using Citrix Chrome Virtual APP and all the popups are opening in new tab.

VMware Horizon docs have clearly mentioned here https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Horizon/2306/horizon-remote-desktop-features/GUID-3CE651AF-96FE-4154-A113-A60A0E49568F.html that it is Browser Content Redirection limitation but couldn't find anything similar in Citrix docs.

Is there any workaround or limitation clearly mentioned in Citrix docs ?

Was expecting the popups to behave normally but opening in new tabs.